Unable to get the column ID or name while dragging it out of the ag-grid to hide or remove it
I'm working on a POC where I need to remove/hide a column when it's dragged out of the ag-grid using gridApi in Angular. But when onDragStopped function being called, none of the column details like colID or column name are being returned. Due to this issue  am not able to update the columnDefs array.
Below is the column definition I've used for the POC.
public columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'col-1',
    field: 'col-1'
  },
  {
    headerName: 'col-2',
    field: 'col-2'
  }
];

I've used the below gridOptions.
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
      suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: false
      onDragStopped: (event) => this.onColumnDragEnd(event)
};

Below is the onColumnDragEnd event code.
onColumnDragEnd(event: any) void{
   const draggedColumn = event.column;
   console.log(draggedColumn) //this is not returning neither the column ID or the name.
}

I'm seeing below details being returned by the console statement.

Is there anyway to get the column ID or  name so that I can compare with the intital colDef and update once the column is dragged out of the ag-grid and remove/hide it in the grid view.
